# How to set UIVIewController to RootViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

I want to know that how can we setup a UIViewController in a UINavigationController without using UITableView to its Root View Controller. Any help regarding this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...
    UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    // ...
}
```

You can replace the class of `myViewController` and/or initialize it using a nib if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


   UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[[OptionViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"OptionViewController" bundle:nil]];
    self.window.rootViewController=nav;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me:

set your tabviewcontroller on window, then it will work properly.

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        UITabBarController *tabVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyMainView"];

        [window setRootViewController:tabVC];
```

Answer (score -3):

UINavigationController pushViewController:animated: